# Count how many variables equal a target value

Tags: sql-server, count, variable

Is there a smart way to count how many variables equal some target value (in SQL Server)?

For example, if I have:

```
declare @a int = 1;
declare @b int = 2;
declare @c int = 1;
declare @target int = 1;
```

Then I'd like to do how many of `@a, @b, @c` eqauls `@target`.

In imperative languages, it's easy to make an inline array of the variables, and then count them - for example in JS:

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 2, target = 1;
if ([a, b, c].filter(item => item == target).length == 1)
   // do something
```

The equivalent in SQL of that "inline array" would be a single column table, but this would require using `DECLARE TABLE`, which I'd like to avoid.

Is there a similarly easy method for such counting in SQL?

Please note I'm less interested in "creating a table without declaring it" - what I really care about is the counting of variables against a target variable, so if it can be done without using tables at all, then it would be better.

Comment: "*but this would require using DECLARE TABLE, which I'd like to avoid*" - Why?...SQL is a relational language and a table is a relation, that is the correct tool for the job. While variables are *available* for use, heavy dependence on them leads to using SQL like a functional language which is not its ideal use. Without using something like a table, I don't think there's a way to accomplish your goal unless you went to some crazy lengths.

Comment: Is there a reason for the need of not using a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this solution?

```
declare @a int = 1;
declare @b int = 2;
declare @c int = 1;
declare @target int = 1;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (VALUES (@a), (@b), (@c)) AS t(_value)
WHERE t._value = @target
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks